# Read individual parts from HTML .txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x

### What I want to achieve?

- I want to download an HTML text file with data of different
  `players`.
- All data has one specific format.
- I want to read specific data about one player and store it.

### This is the data format I am reading (it is all separated by `:`):

```
callsign:cid:realname:clienttype:frequency:latitude:longitude:altitude:groundspeed:planned_aircraft:planned_tascruise:planned_depairport:planned_altitude:planned_destairport:server:protrevision:rating:transponder:facilitytype:visualrange:planned_revision:planned_flighttype:planned_deptime:planned_actdeptime:planned_hrsenroute:planned_minenroute:planned_hrsfuel:planned_minfuel:planned_altairport:planned_remarks:planned_route:planned_depairport_lat:planned_depairport_lon:planned_destairport_lat:planned_destairport_lon:atis_message:time_last_atis_received:time_logon:heading:QNH_iHg:QNH_Mb:
```

---

**That's how I read the HTML file:**

```
import requests

link = "data.vatsim.net/vatsim-data.txt"
f = requests.get(link) 
print(f.text)
```

Comment: So basically you have an XML string and you want to parse it?

Comment: No its a "HTTPS://www.xxxx.com/api.txt/"
Like a HTML Raw.

Comment: So then you need to parse a standard (but huge) HTML file? Can you provide the real link to the source? And for example specific attribute you want to read. So I can provide you with an example.

Comment: Sure, at the top of the page is the principle of how the data is stored.
:callsign:cid:realname: and so on. These are then exchanged with the data below. So for example:

:UAE154:984324:test name:

For example, I only want to know the callsign, the route, the altitude and the ETA (Estimated Time of Arrival). But all of this only from a specific player. I have the real name of this player.

Comment: Can you send here a link from which you are getting this HTML? So I can test my code.

Comment: Woops, thought I pasted it. Sorry. http://data.vatsim.net/vatsim-data.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey hi so this is the working code with explanation:

```
import requests

#Get the data
link = "http://data.vatsim.net/vatsim-data.txt"
f = requests.get(link) 

players = str(f.text).split("!CLIENTS:")[1]

#Find what attributes we want to search for and store their idex inside 'attributes_to_find' dictionary as values
#ETA is not in the data! Couldn't find it.
attributes = "callsign:cid:realname:clienttype:frequency:latitude:longitude:altitude:groundspeed:planned_aircraft:planned_tascruise:planned_depairport:planned_altitude:planned_destairport:server:protrevision:rating:transponder:facilitytype:visualrange:planned_revision:planned_flighttype:planned_deptime:planned_actdeptime:planned_hrsenroute:planned_minenroute:planned_hrsfuel:planned_minfuel:planned_altairport:planned_remarks:planned_route:planned_depairport_lat:planned_depairport_lon:planned_destairport_lat:planned_destairport_lon:atis_message:time_last_atis_received:time_logon:heading:QNH_iHg:QNH_Mb:"
attributes = attributes.split(":")

attributes_to_find = {"callsign":0, "planned_route":0, "altitude":0}

for i, attribute in enumerate(attributes):
    if attribute in attributes_to_find:
        attributes_to_find[attribute] = i

#Function to find the player
def findPlayer(players, name = "None"): 
    players = players.split('\n')

    for player in players: #Search all players
        if name in player: #If name is in player data
            for key, value in attributes_to_find.items(): #Search all attributes that we are looking for and print them
                print("{}: '{}'".format(key, player.split(":")[value]))

            return #If we found it return

findPlayer(players, "Carlos Marques LPPR")
```

---

This is the output of the code above:

```
callsign: 'UAE140'
planned_route: 'ANPUB1B ANPUB P627 GUTOX/N0495F340 P627 KADAP R348 LUXAG/N0485F360 R348 RUPIG UR348 TNV UB536 EROPA UT446 WIV WIV4A'
altitude: '36109'
```

---

I couldn't find the ETA attribute. But if you want to read any other attribute just add it to the `attributes_to_find = {"callsign":0, "planned_route":0, "altitude":0}` dictionary.

Comment: So, I get the Data from the Carlos Marques guy, but when I change the Real name, it still pulls the Data from Carlos. So I get Carlos data everytime.

Comment: Wops my bad! Forgot to split the whole text into individual players ... Now it should work okey! :)

Comment: Its giving now the right data but its pasting 500 lines of code above it

Comment: Look at the answer now. There were 2 print statements  - I deleted them. Now it only prints out the values.

Comment: Another question, is it possible to make out of them variable? For example, callsign is one, altitude is one and route is one, so I each attritube signed to a variable? Because I have to print them singled, not together as one. Regards :)